# Multi level menu with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, menu, multi-level

I have a subject table like this:

```
id
title
parent_id
full_path
```

**`full_path`** is for finding parent as recursive. Like this:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| id | title     | full_path | parent_id |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 40 | home      | 40        |         0 |
| 41 | myhome1   | 41        |         0 |
| 42 | ****      | 40-42     |        40 |
| 43 | *****     | 41-43     |        41 |
| 44 | ***       | 44        |         0 |
| 45 | ****      | 45        |         0 |
| 46 | *****     | 46        |         0 |
| 49 | ******    | 49        |         0 |
| 50 | **** **   | 40-42-50  |        42 |
| 51 | **** **   | 40-42-51  |        42 |
| 52 | **** **   | 40-42-52  |        42 |
| 53 | *******   | 40-53     |        40 |
| 54 | ****      | 40-54     |        40 |
| 55 | ***       | 41-55     |        41 |
| 56 | **** **** | 40-42-56  |        42 |
| 57 | *******   | 44-57     |        44 |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

How i can get an recursive array like this:

```
array
(
    40 => array
    (
        42 => array
        (
            50,51,52,etc.
        ),
        53,
        54
    )
    41 => array
    (
        43,
        55,
    ),
    44 => array
    (
        57,
    ),
    etc...
)
```

Can I use `full_path` for create multilevel menu?

Comment: In my opinion `full_path` is redundant data, so I would delete it from the db.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and we can see where you are going wrong

Comment: @Voitcus without `full_path` how I can create a multi level menu?

Comment: To follow on from what @Voitcus has said, your parent_id would need to be the actual parent, not some other ancestor. Lets take `#50` as an example. Currently `#50`'s `full_path` is `40-42-50`, but in this case, `#42` should be `#50`'s parent, and `#40` should be `#42`'s parent. From `#50` you'd reach `#42` and from `#42` you'd reach `#40` - from there you'd stop the loop as `#40` has no parent.

Comment: what DBMS are u using?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I try again with your tricks.

Comment: @mightyuhu mysql dude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the code below to do this. Keep in mind that this works because your subjects array will be very small and the recursion that happens will be minimal. Dont use this approach on large arrays.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT id, parent_id FROM subjects";
//execute with your prefered method, eg mysqli

$rows = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
  $rows[] = $row;
}

function getChildren($p) {
  global $rows;
  $r = array();
  foreach($rows as $row) {
    if ($row['parent_id']==$p) {
      $r[$row['id']] = getChildren($row['id']);
    }
  }
  return $r;
}

$final = getChildren(0);
?>
```

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but why not put the query inside the `getChildren` function : This query may be filtered with `WHERE parent_id=$p` so, not all rows of the table has to be tested.
Does one query per node is slower than 'foreach on all rows' per node ?

Comment: I dont think it matters much with these numbers. If you do the second approach, make sure you have an index on parent_id.

Answer (score 3):

I edited Hugo's code:

MySQL's code: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eeee7/1)

our table like this:

```
ID | Categories_name | Parent_id
```

our Data is(the numbers on picture, shows id categories):

[image]

our PHP codes:

```
<?php
    $db=mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");
    $db_name = "test";
    mysql_select_db($db_name,$db);


    $query = "SELECT `id`,`cat_name`,`parent_id` FROM `categories`";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $num=mysql_num_rows($result);

    $level_each_rows = array();
    $rows = array();
    for($i = 0 ; $i < $num ; $i++)
    {
        $q_data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $rows[] = $q_data;
    }

    function getChildren_string($p)
    {
        global $rows;
        global $level_each_rows;
        $r = array();
        $i = 0;
        $return = '';
        foreach($rows as $row)
        {
            if ($row['parent_id'] == $p)
            {
                if($row['parent_id'] == 0)
                {
                    $level_each_rows[$row['id']]['i'] = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    $level_each_rows[$row['id']]['i'] = $level_each_rows[$row['parent_id']]['i'] + 1;
                }
                $return = $return.'
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$row['parent_id'].'</td>
                    <td><div style="margin:0px '.($level_each_rows[$row['id']]['i'] * 35).'px;">['.$row['id'].'] - '.$row['cat_name'].'</div></td>
                </tr>

                ';
                $return = $return.getChildren_string($row['id']);
                $i++;
            }
        }
        //---
        return $return;
    }

    $childs = getChildren_string(0);

    echo '
    <div dir="ltr">
        <table dir="ltr" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>Parent ID</td>
                <td>Child ID</td>
            </tr>
    ';
    echo $childs;
    echo '
        </table>
    </div>
    ';
?>
```

**Result:**

[image]