# PHP - MySQL create a tree view from product table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, hierarchical-data

I have a category table as follows. Which I am saving category, subcategories in that table ( Multiple sub-categories ). My table looks like

```
id     |    name       |  parent_of    |   created_on
-------+---------------+---------------+---------------------
1      |   Name 1      |  0            |  2013-05-1 00:00:00
-------+---------------+---------------+---------------------
2      |   Name 2      |  0            |  2013-05-1 00:00:00
-------+---------------+---------------+---------------------
3      |   Name 3      |  1            |  2013-05-1 00:00:00
-------+---------------+---------------+---------------------
4      |   Name 4      |  1            |  2013-05-1 00:00:00
-------+---------------+---------------+---------------------
5      |   Name 5      |  3            |  2013-05-1 00:00:00
-------+---------------+---------------+---------------------
6      |   Name 6      |  3            |  2013-05-1 00:00:00
-------+---------------+---------------+---------------------
```

Now I need to query this table and create a tree structure as follows to make a easy navigation through categories in front end.

A tree like follows

```
1
  |--> 3
  |   |--> 5
  |   |--> 6
  |--> 4
2
```

I am bit confused about the query.
Can anyone please help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1 query for each level / node. Depends on front-end contol.

Comment: thanks for your reply .. can you give me a little more explanation ?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545580/multi-level-menu-with-php/16545992#16545992 for the same type of tree from the same structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For basic display, you may use:

```
SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE `parent_of` = 0;
```

It will give you all the root nodes.

---

When user click on a node, he / she / it submits request to the server (Ajax maybe) to fetch child nodes for clicked one, like:

```
$node = abs((int)$_GET['node']);
```

then:

```
SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE `parent_of` = {$node};
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code logic for your solution,

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, parent_of FROM category WHERE parent_of > 0");

$treeStructure = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $parentID = $row['parent_of'];
    $treeStructure[$parentID][] = $treeStructure[$id];                
}
```